# Failed to open the CloudDBZone because the object type has not been created

Tags: java, android, illegalstateexception, huawei-developers

I'm trying to open an (existing) `AGConnectCloudDB` `CloudDBZone` with Android Java:

```
public void openCloudDBZone(String regionName, boolean isAllowToCreate) {
    CloudDBZoneConfig config = new CloudDBZoneConfig(regionName, syncProperty, accessProperty);
    this.db = AGConnectCloudDB.getInstance(AGConnectInstance.getInstance(), AGConnectAuth.getInstance());
    this.db.openCloudDBZone2(config, isAllowToCreate)
            .addOnSuccessListener(cloudDBZone -> {
                zone = cloudDBZone;
            }).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
            });
}
```

This fails with an `IllegalStateException` from `com.huawei.hmf.tasks`:

> Failed to open the CloudDBZone because the object type has not been created.

I've defined the object-types in the AGConnect console and also as `CloudDBZoneObject`.
Version number is `1.5.4.300`, which has `ObjectTypeInfo` but no `ObjectTypeInfoHelper`:

```
implementation 'com.huawei.agconnect:agconnect-cloud-database:1.5.4.300'
```

What does this error message mean and what to do about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having found the "Export" button (the screenshot in the documentation doesn't match the GUI, where it can be found inside the menu), I've also found the `ObjectTypeInfoHelper.java` in the downloaded zip file. Working code for reference:

```
private AGConnectCloudDB db;
private CloudDBZone zone;

private final CloudDBZoneConfig.CloudDBZoneSyncProperty syncProperty =
        CloudDBZoneConfig.CloudDBZoneSyncProperty.CLOUDDBZONE_CLOUD_CACHE;

private final CloudDBZoneConfig.CloudDBZoneAccessProperty accessProperty =
        CloudDBZoneConfig.CloudDBZoneAccessProperty.CLOUDDBZONE_PUBLIC;

private final CloudDBZoneQuery.CloudDBZoneQueryPolicy queryPolicy =
        CloudDBZoneQuery.CloudDBZoneQueryPolicy.POLICY_QUERY_DEFAULT;

/** class ObjectTypeInfoHelper originates from the downloaded zip file. */
public void openCloudDBZone(String zoneName, boolean isAllowToCreate) {
    try {
        CloudDBZoneConfig config = new CloudDBZoneConfig(zoneName, syncProperty, accessProperty);
        this.db = AGConnectCloudDB.getInstance(AGConnectInstance.getInstance(), AGConnectAuth.getInstance());
        this.db.createObjectType(ObjectTypeInfoHelper.getObjectTypeInfo());
        this.db.openCloudDBZone2(config, isAllowToCreate)
                .addOnSuccessListener(cloudDBZone -> {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "CloudDBZone opened: " + zoneName);
                    zone = cloudDBZone;
                }).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
                });
    } catch (AGConnectCloudDBException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void closeCloudDBZone() {
    try {
        this.db.closeCloudDBZone(this.zone);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "CloudDBZone closed.");
    } catch (AGConnectCloudDBException e) {
        Log.w(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The difference is `ObjectTypeInfoHelper.getObjectTypeInfo()`.

---

And I've also wrote a `TypeConverter`, which converts `CloudDBZoneObject` to `BaseObservable`  (read) and `BaseObservable` to `CloudDBZoneObject` (write). Alike this data-binding isn't an issue anymore.